# MySQL JOIN on possible other id if not null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join another table but couldn't get it to work.
[SQLfiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/307a04/2)

table :

```
CREATE TABLE service_order
(id int,
id_default_support_worker int,
id_custom_support_worker int);
    
INSERT INTO service_order
values(1, 1, null), (2,1, null),(3,1, null),(4,4, 2);

CREATE TABLE support_worker
(id int,
name VARCHAR(20));
    
INSERT INTO support_worker
  values(1, 'support_worker 1'), (2,'support_worker 2'),(3,'support_worker 3'),(4,'support_worker 4');

CREATE TABLE result_service_order
(id int,
id_service_order int,
descr VARCHAR(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO result_service_order
values(1, 1, 'desc 1'), (2, 1,'desc 2'),(3, 1,'desc 3'),(4, 4,'desc 4');;
```

What I'm trying to do is join on service_order.id_custom_support_worker only if service_order.id_custom_support_worker is not NULL.

```
SELECT RSO.descr , SW.name
FROM result_service_order RSO
LEFT JOIN service_order SO ON RSO.id_service_order = SO.id
INNER JOIN support_worker SW ON SW.id = SO.id_default_support_worker --here
```

Currently I'm fiddeling whit COALESCE as sugested in another tred but couldn't get it to work.
Is there somebody who can help me whit this join if result is NULL??

Comment: It is strange to have an inner join after outer join in your case. I believe that you obtain always the same result if you use exclusively inner joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns custom_support_worker if set, default_support_worker otherwise:

```
INNER JOIN support_worker SW
    ON ( SW.id = COALESCE( SO.id_custom_support_worker, SO.id_default_support_worker ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood, you want to do third join if custom_support_worker is not null so i
suggest change third join condition to `INNER JOIN support_worker SW ON SW.id = SO.id_custom_support_worker` this.

`SELECT RSO.descr , SW.name FROM result_service_order RSO LEFT JOIN service_order SO ON RSO.id_service_order = SO.id INNER JOIN support_worker SW ON SW.id = SO.id_custom_support_worker;`